# How to change partition permissions with fstab?

Tags: permissions, samba, fstab

I have an Ext4 partition on my HDD which I am trying to use as a samba share.

The samba share is visible, but not accessible from any device on the network, and after some troubleshooting, I have found that this is caused by the partition not being accessible without administrator permissions: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9Piy.jpg

The line for the partition in /etc/fstab is as follows:

```
UUID=72eb5ecb-ccb9-4f2c-a357-0cdbee75609a /mnt/storage ext4 defaults,x-gvfs-show,rw 0 2
```

This is what the permissions look like for the partition and and folders and files within: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPX9D.jpg

I was able to list the contents of the partition but not access them, but I am no longer able to do so after trying to set the permissions of the partition to 666 recursively with chmod (which did not work, as it only changed the permissions for the files on the partition), then remounting the partition.

It appears I am able to change the permissions of the partition with nautilus after authenticating, but it changes back after restarting the computer or remounting the partition, and I haven't tested if it makes the samba share accessible.

I want to change the partition permissions so that any user and the samba software can access and read and write to the partition, with fstab, so that I don't have to manually authenticate and change the permissions every time the partition is remounted or the computer restarted. I haven't found any information on how to do this or how to solve this problem except for a solution to a similar problem which is specific to the NTFS file system (with umask, which doesn't work for Ext4).

Comment: I can't test it, but can you try `UUID=72eb5ecb-ccb9-4f2c-a357-0cdbee75609a /mnt/storage ext4 x-gvfs-show 0 0`. It's just a hunch based on my setup.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I changed the line in /etc/fstab to what you suggested. I tested it after remounting the partition and restarting the computer. It didn't work either time, and seemed to behave in the same way as before.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time. I thought it was worth a try.

Comment: Try changing the access permission of the mounted drive. Say if you mount the partition at `/mnt/storage` then try `sudo chmod -R a+rX /mnt/storage`

Comment: @BernardWei Thanks! It didn't occur to me that the execute permission is required to access a partition. It works just fine, even after I remount the partition or restart the computer.